# How do I import 2 specific bands from different landsat platforms into python?

Tags: python, landsat

I have a folder of unzipped files from Landsat 5, Landsat 7, and Landsat 8. I want to import the red and NIR bands to run NDVI. But, this means I need to bring in bands 4 and 5 for Landsat 8, and bands 3 and 4 for Landsat's 5 and 7. I am having a hard time writing a code to just import these bands. I am completely new to python so this might be way off, but here is what I have:

```
import os
import arcpy
import re

from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

mydir = r"E:\Thesis\005005-006004\005005\US_Landsat_4-8_ARD"
```

## directory to store indices

```
rasters = r"E:\Thesis\Processing\005005"
```

## lists for images & corresponding xml files

```
P_2Band = []

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(mydir):
    for name in files:
        if name.startswith("LC08")
            if name.endswith("4.tif") or if name.endswith("5.tif"):
                mypath = root+"\\"+name
                P_2Band.append(mypath)
                print(name)

        elif name.startswith("LE07") or if name.startswith("LT05")
            if name.endswith("3.tif" or "4.tif"):
                mypath = root+"\\"+name
                P_Metadata.append(mypath)
                print(name)
```

Thanks for any help!